# Compile troubles c to c++ trans

Tags: c++, c

I am unsure what exactly is wrong with this... It won't compile for me, I translated it from c to C++ (or attempted to)... and yes I'm a beginner.  Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char * argv[], char* env[]) {
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

    /* print query string only */
    cout << "%s\n",getenv("QUERY_STRING");

    /* print the while environment */
    while (env[i]) cout << "%s\n",env[i++];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Technically you should #include <cstdlib> and <cstdio>, these are the C++ names for the equivalent C headers.

Comment: No offense intended, but that `cout << "%s"` idea's kind of cute ;-).

Comment: thanks... I guess; I can take the heat, I know my place in line...

Comment: I get the error "premature end of script headers" when I try to run this with my webpage?

Answer (score 4):

Change these:

```
cout << "%s\n",getenv("QUERY_STRING");
```

Into this:

```
cout << getenv("QUERY_STRING") << endl;
```

Same goes for the other one too, (EDIT:) like this:

```
while (env[i]) cout << env[i++] << endl;
```

Comment: like so? // while (env[i]) cout << getenv("QUERY_STRING"),env[i++]; << endl;
//

Comment: I get the error "premature end of script headers" when I try to run this with my webpage?

Comment: It sounds as if you are trying to run this code as a Perl CGI script. You need a C++ compiler for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `cout`, you should `#include <iostream>`. Then it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char * argv[], char* env[]) {
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

    /* print query string only */
    cout << getenv("QUERY_STRING") << endl;

    /* print the while environment */
    while (env[i]) cout << env[i++] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output with std::cout does not use %s or %d like printf, you have to put the variable or value after <<.